# c# Access DB running multiple queries

Tags: c#

very new to all the c# stuff but have built a program that does the job so I'm satisfied with my coding so far as it basically does what I want it to. My problem is I currently display a datagridview on button click if the the table matches 3 comboboxes (i.e. select banner, store, and year and the grid will populate). Now I want to populate a second datagridview, pulled from a different table that references all the cells (10 in total) in a specific column (Column 4) in grid#1 and I cant for the life of me figure it out! basically check he 2nd table against the values in the 4th column on grid1. below is what i use to populate the 1st grid

```
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select *from  
        ShortageAllYears_2 where Stores LIKE '"+cboStore_2.Text+"' and 
        YEARS LIKE '"+cboYear.Text+"'", conn);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(data);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = data;
```

yes Halil Ibrahim, I'm trying to fill a 2nd datagridview by referencing values in the 1st one...I'm also using access databse for my tables if that helps...in the 1st gridview if use a my cascading dropdown boxes I would end up with query that asks if the table contains this store and this year populate the datagrid...that works fine and displays the 7 columns with the 10 rows I need...in column 4 there are departments numbers with a corresponding dollars in the next column....I want to run a 2nd datagrid where I can ask "if the table contains a different store (selected by a different combobox), same year but only return departments contained in the 1st grid (column 4, 10 rows)". if I only wanted to return 1 row I could populate a textbox with the department number and add 'where DEPT LIKE '"+textbox1.text+"' -and that works-but I need all 10 department #'s. I'm so sorry if this sounds confusing as I'm not even sure how to ask the question.

as a workaround i created a multiple data adapters in the same connection and used the same data table...to pull info from the first DGV to use as a query against a separate DB and populate a second DGV I used something like (no code in front of me) Select * from DB where Dept like '"+datagridview1.rows[0].cells[4].value.tostring()+"' and it worked perfectly for my use...

Comment: Never glue data and strings together to make SQL.  Always use SQL Parameters.  Always

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. are you trying to populate grid2 by parameterizing grid1's col4 ?

Comment: What have you tried?  And as Disaffected said; use params, please!

Comment: I've edited my original post

Comment: I think I figured out a workaround...see my original post

Comment: You should be able to use two DataTables and display into two DGV.  You  have a DataConnections and a DataCommand.  The adapter takes the command and automatically fills the DataTable and create links between Command and the DataTable so when you update the table data also gets pushed back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a workaround for the original question. @Disaffected 1070452 brought up a Very Good point though. Always use parameters. To do this with your query would be simple.

```
SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText =  "select *from  ShortageAllYears_2 where Stores LIKE @stores and YEARS LIKE @years"
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stores, cboStores_2.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@years, cboYear.Text);
var result = command.ExecuteReader();
```

At that point you can do whatever you want with the values in result. I am sure you can adapt this to work with the OleDbDataAdapter also. This is how I have implemented it in the past though.

There are various reasons to use SQL Parameters but one of the biggest is SQL Injection. Depending on how the data is being entered if you just glue the data into the statement you may open yourself up to statements including Table Drop commands or Gets that pull sensitive data.

This is a good reference for this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Those parameters shouldn't be in quotes.

Comment: @LarsTech good call. I didn't realize I put them in quotes. All fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on parameters... I’ll have to do some research because I learned using quotes and now confused

Comment: It may seem a little strange but it is just a way of adding the value to the query with a level of abstraction that you don't get just putting them inline. Think of `@stores` as a variable that you are assigning a value to with the `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` method.